# Status of final rank in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on the ranking of domestic competition of soccer,
I have the following dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df ['Season'] = ['1314','1314','1314','1314','1314','1314','1314','1314','1314','1415','1415','1415','1415','1415','1415','1415','1415','1415']
df ['Team'] = ['A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C']
df ['GW'] = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
df['Position'] = [1,2,3,3,1,2,2,3,1,2,1,3,2,1,3,3,2,1]
df = df.sort_values (['Season','Team'])
df['Position_Change']=df.groupby(['Season','Team'])['Position'].apply(lambda x : x.diff().fillna(0))
```

Above code can track the rank and position change.
Now I wanted to assign a status to the team which ends as first as **Champion**. That means the status champion will be assigned to that team in all GW. And the other teams as the position where they ended at  last week of the competition (in this sample last GW is 3)
My expected output is as follow:

[image]

Here is the  original dataset:
[Click to download the dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UBxw8KCL1128RTvS6lVFC2lOslYjhDxz)

Your advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Zep

Comment: in this example, the last week of the competition is week 3. so We will look at the rank of each team at week 3. if a team's rank at GW3 is 1, that team is champion. so I will create a new column to note the status where  Team C is champion for season 1314 and 1415. But the status "Champion" for C will be for all GW in that year. Similar for second and third. Do let me know if you need more info.

Comment: you would require `np.select()` for each group, check below answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you need something like below:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Season','Team'])['Position'].apply(lambda x : np.select([(x.iloc[-1]==1),(x.iloc[-1]==2),(x.iloc[-1]==3)],['Champion','Second','Third'])).reset_index().rename(columns={'Position':'Status'})
print(df.merge(df1,on=['Team','Season']))

    Season Team  GW  Position  Position_Change    Status
0    1314    A   1         1              0.0    Second
1    1314    A   2         3              2.0    Second
2    1314    A   3         2             -1.0    Second
3    1314    B   1         2              0.0     Third
4    1314    B   2         1             -1.0     Third
5    1314    B   3         3              2.0     Third
6    1314    C   1         3              0.0  Champion
7    1314    C   2         2             -1.0  Champion
8    1314    C   3         1             -1.0  Champion
9    1415    A   1         2              0.0     Third
10   1415    A   2         2              0.0     Third
11   1415    A   3         3              1.0     Third
12   1415    B   1         1              0.0    Second
13   1415    B   2         1              0.0    Second
14   1415    B   3         2              1.0    Second
15   1415    C   1         3              0.0  Champion
16   1415    C   2         3              0.0  Champion
17   1415    C   3         1             -2.0  Champion
```

*Based on Chat, replace code for df1 in the original code by:*

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Season','Team'])['Position'].apply(lambda x : np.select([(x.iloc[-1]==1),(2<=x.iloc[-1]<=4),(5<=x.iloc[-1]<=6),(7<=x.iloc[-1]<=17),(x.iloc[-1] > 17)],['Champion','UCL','UEL','Other','Relegation'])).reset_index().rename(columns={'Position':'Status'})
```

Comment: It work for this example. what it I want to use range of rank instead of 2.
That means 1>rank <=4. As my actual data is up to 20.

Comment: I am trying your code with logical in between. Now running. Let’s see if it works

Comment: Can you share a valid data frame example please do i can test better. :)

Comment: Can I upload the data file in original post?

Comment: Yes sure, also unaccept this answer after you edit the question. That way users would have better visibility to this question :)

Comment: Just added the link. Thanks for the help.

Comment: here is the logic: Status for position 1  is champion, 2 to 4 is UCL, 5 to 6 UEL, 7 to 17 Other, >17 Relegation.

Comment: @Zephyr : got it, but this check is for each group's last week ryt? or for every row in the group?

Comment: Similar concept as the example. I mean in this case is GW 38is last game. So all logic above is based on GW38.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186933/discussion-between-anky-91-and-zephyr).